# How to deal with empty node in xquery?

Tags: xml, xquery, xidel

I want to print a TSV output like this. But when `$x/span` does not find anything, there will be only two columns printed. How to insert an empty field in the 2nd column when `$x/span` finds nothing? Thanks.

```
for $x in //td/b/a[@title]/parent::b/parent::td
return join(
    (
        $x/b/a/@title
        , $x/span
        , $x/p
    )
    , x:cps(9)
)
```

Comment: Please share two things: (1) your input XML, and (2) desired output.

Comment: What does the join() function do? It's not a standard XQuery function.

Comment: @MichaelKay http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-join

Comment: @user1424739 An XPath expression would be enough in this case. You could simplify it to: `-e '//td[b/a[@title]]/join((b/a/@title,(span,"")[1],p),x:cps(9))'`.

Comment: @Reino OK. This is even better. Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XPath:**

```
//td[b/a[@title]]/join(
  (
    b/a/@title,
    (span,"")[1],
    p
  ),
  x:cps(9)
)
```

**XQuery:**

```
for $x in //td[b/a[@title]] return
$x/join(
  (
    b/a/@title,
    (span,"")[1],
    p
  ),
  "&#9;"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if/else` statement to control what to do in case of the missing **span** tag.

```
if (empty($x/span)) then  
    (: do what you need here :)
else  
    $x/span
```

Comment: I don’t want to rewrite the whole join statement. Is there a way to assign the middle column value to a variable depending on whether $x/span is empty or not?

Comment: @user1424739, you don't need to rewrite the entire `join` statement. Just replace the `$x/span` with the expression I showed.

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom for this is

```
($x/span, "default")[1]
```

But this might not be right for you if `$x/span` can select multiple items.

Comment: For my case, $x/span can return either 0 or 1 element. So this works for my case. And this solution is more succinct than the solution by @YitzhakKhabinsky. So I'd consider this solution is better.